# Redirect https request on local network

Tags: iptables, dnsmasq, https

I'm trying to implement a local web server that handle all the http requests. Basically, when a user connect to the network and open an url, he is redirected to my local web server.

I'm using dns mask for this purpose and it works pretty well for HTTP traffic. The problem is with the HTTPS traffic (especially the case when a user perform a search in the chrome navigation bar). I tried running the server on https with some iptables rules without success.

Is there a way to redirect the https traffic to my local web server ?

Thanks

Comment: The redirection you are doing is not a matter of protocols (http/https), but of the ip-address you provide with dnsmasq. So if the redirection does not work for one particular protocol, then the server on the other end (your webserver) does not seem to listen for the needed port (443 in your case)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gerhardd. You were right my server wasn't listening correctly on 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection you are doing is not a matter of protocols (http/https), but of the ip-address you provide with dnsmasq.

So if the redirection does not work for one particular protocol, then the server on the other end (your webserver) does not seem to listen for the needed port (443 in your case)